# Как в selenium подключить профиль в webdriver.Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-2.7

С Firefox все было просто: находишь файл профиля и одной строчкой все срабатывало, но как быть с хромом?

Comment: Для хрома тоже есть файл профиля

Answer (score 1):

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ отсюда качаешь файл Chromedriver

Google Chrome Driver    2.21  (на момент ответа). 
Размещаешь файл в удобное для себя место, я обычно закидываю его в папку с Селениумом. В инициализации вебдрайвера прописываешь путь к этому файлу.

Вот как это выглядит у меня:

```
drive = webdriver.Chrome("C:/External Python libs/selenium-2.53.2/chromedriver.exe")
```